# Joining Object Array keys

Tags: c#

I have an object Array

```
Dummy[] arr = {Dummy1, Dummy2}
```

I want to join comma separated `keys` of each Dummy object in that array. This doesn't work.

```
string blah = string.Join(", ", arr)
```

Comment: Override the toString() of Dummy object to return the Key! Or select the Key and join

Comment: It "doesn't work" because you've made no attempt to access the key.

Comment: Post the Dummy class.

Comment: @itsme86 , that was my problem. I couldn't get key value. Tried arr.Key, that doesn't work, obviously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
string blah = string.Join(", ", arr.Select(dummy => dummy.Key));
```